# Terminal Window Hangs for 4-5 sec. Consistently

Tags: 14.04, freeze

I'm an Ubuntu 14.04 noob, and this really annoying thing keeps happening.  Every 30 sec. or so the terminal window will hang, but it registers everything I type and will display it after a 4-5 sec. time lag.  It mostly happens in the terminal window, but sometimes this can happen in other text editors that I like to use or when typing in Firefox or Chromium.  I tried opening the system monitor, but it doesn't look like anything is running in the background that could be causing this issue.  Help!!!!  Also, I've tried rebooting -> helps for a little bit, but then the problem resurfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out! A program called Orca was starting itself on startup and using up a cpu at 100%.  Apparently Orca is a screen reader, ugh!!